# Hidden field value not passing to next page in Spring Portlets

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm using spring portlets and I have a form with a hidden field within the form. When submitting the form hidden field value is in the request (tested using Tamper Data) and it is not coming to next page's controller (formBacking method). Here is the code.

```
function(){
formname.hiddenfield.value="value";
}

<form action="url" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="field1" name="field1" value="val"/>

<input type="submit" value="button"/>
</form>

protected Object formBackingObject(PortletRequest request) throws Exception {
String variable1 = request.getParameter("field1");
}
```

when I check for request parameters, I cannot find any name.

Comment: Are you submitting the correct form?

Comment: It's not going to solve this problem, but you should namespace your portlet IDs to avoid conflicts. AS you are using Spring Portlet MVC you may well find it more convenient to bind your form directly to your controller using @ModelAttribute

Comment: @SujithMaliyadda Did you monitor the network to check if the form indeed is carrying the hidden field (If using Chrome, check it on the `Network Tab` while Inspecting the Element)? Does your url corresponds to `Action` or `Render` or `Resource`? If so, why are you using `PortletRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

By Default a Portlet sends an Action Request to the Self Portlet. If it has to go to the Next Page's Controller, the Form Action URL should be one of the portlets of Next Page only.